# How to fetch data as an array from MySQL and populate text field dynamically based on dropdown selection in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have two categories of **Job Applicants** in my database: **graduates** and **artisans**. I am trying to fetch their emails separately base on the category being selected from the  drop down menu.

My objective is to fetch all the emails as an array and populate them into a text field.

for clarity, here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-line">
<select class="form-control smode" name="smode" id="smode" >
<option value="">select Job Seekers</option>
<option value="G">Graduates Only</option>
<option value="A">Artisans Only</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Email List</label>
<div class="form-item">
<input type="text" name="email_list" class="form-control" /><!--Field to populate--!>
</div>                                 
</div>
```

**Js**

```
$('#smode').change(function(){
var packages = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   data:{packages:packages},
   url:'get_email.php',
   success:function(data){
       $('#email_list').val(data);
   } 

});
```

**get_email.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['packages'])) {
    $g =  $_POST['packages'];
    $qry = "select * from jobseeker WHERE confirm_no LIKE '$g'";
    $rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($rec) > 0) {

        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($rec);

        foreach ($res as $rs) {
            $emailArr[] = stripslashes(($rs["mails"]));
        }

        $emails = implode(";", $emailArr);

        echo $emails;

    }
}
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? It looks like it should work.

Comment: @Barmar, I believe so but it is not working.

Comment: Is it getting any errors? Have you checked the Javascript console, particularly the Network tab to see the raw data being returned?

Comment: @Barmar, no, it's not generating any error. i have checked the console also.

Comment: Without more details, it's impossible to answer your question. What happens if you put `echo "Here are the emails";` at the beginning of the PHP, does that show up in the result?

Comment: You're missing a `});` in your Javascript.

Comment: Is it sending the AJAX request at all? Maybe you need to put the Javascript inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar,  I have tried everything possible but still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I asked some specific questions, you should answer them if you want more help.

Comment: Or you just need to learn basic debugging techniques on your own. Set breakpoints in the Javascript debugger. Add `echo` and `var_dump` statements to the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JQuery guru, but I know that Javascript doesn't care for single quotes.  Is JQuery similar?  (Sorry, I can't add comments yet)